# Standardize multiple variables

Tags: loops, stata

I need to standardize hundreds of variables in a text file that has `id` as first column and varlist in subsequent columns using Stata. After conversion, I need to export the new file that only has `id` (first column) and all standardized values to my directory.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly

```
ds id, not 

foreach v in `r(varlist)' { 
    tempvar work 
    egen `work' = std(`v') 
    drop `v' 
    rename `work' `v'
}
```

See `help egen` to check that its idea of standardization matches yours

Comment: @motor30 If this worked for you, can you select it as the answer using the checkmark?